# Change color of random text in an array

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a question, what if I have 50 strings in an array and I want to make the ones longer than 5letters have a red color, how do I do it?
Please show help using the .map(function (element, index)if... method thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set color of a `string`. You can use this objects: `{string:<string>,isRed:false}`, and the can use `for` loop:

```
for(let stringObj of strings) {stringObj.isRed=stringObj.string.lenght>5} //strings: that array which contains the 50 string object
```